# How can I change the state of the itemRenderer of one member of a flex 4 spark data group?

Tags: flex4, components, itemrenderer, states

I have a "step indicator" made out of a DataGroup:

```
<s:DataGroup id="stepNumbers" itemRenderer="stepNumberRenderer" horizontalCenter="0">
<s:layout>
<s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle"/>
</s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

where the dataprovider is 1,2,3,4,5.

The item renderer has 2 states, "normal" and "active".  Within Actionscript, I’d like to be able to set each number to "active" in as needed.  So, I need to set "2" to its active state, i.e. stepNumbers[1].  What's the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item:stepNumberRenderer;
var active:int = 2;

for(var i:uint = 0; i < stepNumbers.numElements; i++)
{
    item = stepNumbers.getElementAt(i) as stepNumberRenderer;
    If(i == active)
      item.currentState = "active";
    else
      item.currentState = "normal";
}
```